# Can't create .edmx file for postgresql use entityframework + npgsql

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I want to create ADO.NET entity data model - database first (.edmx file) with EntityFramework6.Npgsql but it's error. I have installed:
- EntityFramework6.Npgsql (version 6.3 newest)
- Npgsql (version 4.1.1 newest)
- EntityFramework (version 6.3 newest)

[image: https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2019/10/23/Untitledd14771b27d08a488.png]

I created it before, but I don't know why now! Please help me....

Comment: This is error message: The type initializer for 'Npgsql.TypeMapping.GlobalTypeMapper' threw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that is [already tracked on github](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2670#issuecomment-543246657)

> In the meantime for those having issues with the latest version of the
>   VSIX (4.1.1.2), please downgrade back to 4.0.x.

So downgrade your Npgsql version and extension version.

Comment: ok, in this case [you can accept my reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to "close" the question.

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." So sorry :D

Comment: ok, be active and answer other questions and if you get upvotes, [you'll get reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: Hi @magicandre1981, do you have any idea where I can find previous versions of the Npgsql PostgreSQL Integration extension? I can't seem to find a version history in the VS marketplace. Thanks.

Comment: @Joseph get older [releases on github](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/releases?after=v5.0.0-alpha1) an disable automatic extension update in VS

Comment: @magicandre1981 I tried that but I cannot find the VSIX files. Any idea where they are for each release? EDIT: Never mind, I've seen them. Thanks