# Postgresql: connection gives exception

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have the following code to connect to a Postgresql database:

```
this.connectionString = "Server=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=admin;Database=TestDb;Port=5433";
this.con = new NpgsqlConnection(this.connectionString);
this.con.Open();
```

Server, username, password and database name are correct.
However, I get the following error when running the last line:

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Npgsql.TypeMapping.GlobalTypeMapper' threw an exception.'

Comment: See if this answer can help. [TypeInitializerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60330797/the-type-initializer-for-npgsql-typemapping-globaltypemapper-threw-an-exceptio)

Comment: @Riyas, thanks. In Windows File Explorer, I pasted the XML into csproj as a child node of the Project tag. However, I still get the same error.